# Trouble with Java GUI

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I am creating a GUI for my project. I am completely stuck at one point. I was able to create a GUI which will make some simple queries like the release number, command name, and few other boolean questions.

Now I want the user to press <kbd>CONTINUE</kbd> button to move to the next page of the GUI form. I have created the continue button, but now I need to register an event to it. This is where I am stuck. I have no idea what event can I register to it which will move the GUI to next page.  (By moving to the next page I mean, the different GUI pages we see when we are installing a software for our computer.)

For instance, if I am installing iTunes, I'd first select the radio button for "I accept the terms and conditions" and then I'd press the <kbd>CONTINUE</kbd> or the <kbd>NEXT</kbd> button to move ahead. If I need to come back, I'd press the <kbd>BACK</kbd> button.

One logical answer would be to create another GUI form and then link it to the one I created first.

EDIT:: this is the first time I am working in Java, so I might have ignored some obvious facts.

Comment: *"One logical answer would be to create another GUI form and then link it to the one I created first."*  See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)
This GUI needs a `CardLayout`

Answer (score 1):

Look into using a CardLayout, adding several JPanels to the CardLayout-using container, and then to swap to the next view (the next JPanel), call the layout's `next(...)` method in the JButton's ActionListener. You could also randomly access components held by the CardLayout using its `show(...)` method.

To learn more about this including sample code, please have a look at the [CardLayout Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html), and the [API](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/CardLayout.html).

Comment: The way the OP posted his question, you may want to include what an ActionListener is.

Comment: @Angelo: You have a point. I would hope that he has enough initiative to look up how Swing JButton's work before coming here, but you never know.

Comment: My description might have been vague, but I DO know all about actionListeners and JButtons.

Comment: @iSmite: then to avoid making us guess on this, please make your questions more informative and more specific. And use a CardLayout as that is the solution to your current problem.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I tried to explain in as much detail as possible. This is my first programming experience with Java and I am quite overwhelmed with all the new stuff.

Comment: @iSmite: that's OK. Asking good questions here is also a skill, one that gets better with experience. Don't sweat our criticisms, but do use them for future reference.

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels yeah, constructive criticism. :D

Answer (score 1):

Well, register an `ActionListener` or an `Action` with the button. To do that wizard style, have a look at the `CardLayout` layout manager to switch cards or use a tabbed pane, hide the tabs and switch them inside the action or action listener.

Answer (score 1):

if i understood, i think you should use the CardLayout

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Swing, you can using several instances of JPanel over a one instance of JFrame.

You can have something like that structure:

```
JFrame
  +------JPanel:root
           |
           +---JPanel:current // This panel change by other instance
           |
           +---JPanel:controlPanel // This panel contains you button
```

In you button need add a ActionListener with the method addActionListener

The panel control may need changes your elements, may the text of button or remove the listener and change by other.

I hope that can help